# How does one see chatroom comments with a particular tag?

Tags: support, tagging, search, chat

[This appears to be a new question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVIAo.jpg)

[I found out recently](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48219852#48219852) that one can use tags in chat. They're given by the code `[tag:tag-name]`.

> How does one see chatroom comments with a particular tag?

I'm guessing there'll be hidden gems to find, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can use to your advantage is that [Search is looking at the HTML encoded version of a post, rather than what would be rendered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146213).

Since every tag generates link of the form `site/tagged/tagname` you can try to search for "tagged/tagname". Notice that this will also return all [oneboxed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/onebox/info) questions posted in chat with this tag. But if the phrase is quite common this can eliminated some false positives. (As a typical use case I could imagine that users of some room would agree to use some tag for messages related to some specific topic - so that this makes searching for them easier.)

Since this is dependent on the way the Stack Exchange chat is *implemented* in the moment, there is no guarantee that this won't change in the future. (But I have not heard about some big changes regarding chat in the near future.)

Some examples: [duplicates](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22tagged%2Fduplicates%22&room=2165) in CRUDE, [functional-analysis](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22tagged%2Ffunctional-analysis%22&room=36) in the main chatroom, [new-tag](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22tagged%2Fnew-tag%22&room=3740) in Tagging. (You can compare this with results when searching simply for [duplicates](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=duplicates&room=2165), [functional-analysis](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=functional-analysis&room=36), [new-tag](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=new-tag&room=3740) in the respective rooms.)